# Excel - how to NOT a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm testing an Excel formula that returns Boolean (True or False)

This one works fine:

`=OR(ISBLANK(B2),AND(LEN(B2)=12,ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(FIND(MID(B2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:12")),1),"0123456789abcdefABCDEF")))))`

Now I want to reverse the result.  So I wrap a `NOT()` around it.  But Excel won't take it.  Why?  Thanks!

`=NOT(OR(ISBLANK(B2),AND(LEN(B2)=12,ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(FIND(MID(B2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:12")),1),"0123456789abcdefABCDEF"))))))`

Comment: What do you mean by "[it] won't take it"? Is there an error message?

Comment: I've found isnumber(hex2dec(b2)) to be an effective test for macs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate a MAC address (or find non-valid ones) split the address into 2 hexadecimals of 6 each and attempt a HEX2DEC conversion.

```
'validate
=OR(LEN(B2)=0, AND(LEN(B2)=12, IFERROR(HEX2DEC(LEFT(B2, 6))*HEX2DEC(RIGHT(B2, 6)), FALSE)))
=OR(LEN(B2)=0, AND(LEN(B2)=12, ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(HEX2DEC(LEFT(B2, 6)), HEX2DEC(RIGHT(B2, 6))))))
'find non-valid
=NOT(OR(LEN(B2)=0, AND(LEN(B2)=12, IFERROR(HEX2DEC(LEFT(B2, 6))*HEX2DEC(RIGHT(B2, 6)), FALSE))))
=NOT(OR(LEN(B2)=0, AND(LEN(B2)=12, ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(HEX2DEC(LEFT(B2, 6)), HEX2DEC(RIGHT(B2, 6)))))))
```

This is essentially what your original formula does but with less calculation load. tbh, I'm not sure why your NOT wrapper didn't work; it did for me.